# Temp Table Creation in SQL

Tags: mysql

Could someone help me with this? I have couple of tables with some data. I need to query this table for the number of rows processed per day and load into another table:

```
Table1:
PNO    ModelNo   OrderNo    CustID   DAY
1      100012    1000AY     2345     31-AUG
2      109014    100YT8     3452     01-AUG
2      109014    100YT8     3452     31-AUG

Table2:
AN    DAST    CODE    ROWS   DAY
19    VEN     EFD     19     31-AUG
21    EHT     UYE     21     01-SEP
22    VEG     WTE     24     01-SEP

Final Table:
DAY       Source     Rows
31-AUG    Table1       2
01-SEP    Table1       1
31-AUG    Table2       1
01-SEP    Table2       2
```

*Source: should be the table name.

Should I have to use Temp table or create a inner query concept and do it? Would like to know which is effecient. Please help.

Keep you updated: that all of these table are created under same schema..

Comment: May I ask, why you need this kind of table?

Comment: So we need to send our customer how many rows are getting processed for each day for each data source(table) to our end customer. We are planning to load into the seperate table as well to take a readymade backup.

Answer (score 0):

As Shaharyar suggests, the reasons for actually creating such a table are probably questionable at best. However, the query to create the resulting table:

```
SELECT 'Table1' as Source, COUNT(*) as Rows, DAY FROM Table1 GROUP BY DAY
UNION
SELECT 'Table2' as Source, COUNT(*) as Rows, DAY FROM Table2 GROUP BY DAY
```

This doesn't scale very well for many tables. Though. Also, it would be preferable to add indexes on the `DAY` columns.

If you actually want to generate a manifested table, this might do the job:

```
CREATE TABLE final_table SELECT ...
```

Comment: Is it not possible to generate the table name dynamically from FROM cluase? Instead of hard coading the table name in select clause??

Comment: The problem is, the actual table name is not data. sql allows you to switch, manipulate and whatever you want to do with data ... but you can't generate the query itself that easily ... (you need udf or other advanced stuff)